# Get everything before dot or comma c#

Tags: c#, .net, par

how can I get a substring of everything before dot or comma?

For example:

```
    string input = "2.1";
int charLocation = text.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    string test = input.Substring(0, charLocation );
```

but what if I have an `input = "2,1"` ?

I would like to do it in one method, not using twice a substring (once for dot and once for comma)?

Comment: Are you attempting to parse decimal values that may come from varying locales? If so, please update your question. There are better ways.

Comment: Or you could use a RegEx, then you will have two problems :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string test = input.Split(new Char[] { ',', '.' })[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will split the string for either comma or period...

```
input.Split(',','.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the IndexOfAny function. It allows you to specify a list of characters to look for, rather than just a single character. You could then make a substring up to the return value of that function.

e.g.

```
char[] chars = { '.', ',' }
String out = s.Substring(0,s.IndexOfAny(chars));
```